# Using a 32-bit JRE with a 64-bit Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I had setup 64-bit eclipse with 64-bit JRE. I wanted to try QuickTime for Java but I realized that it is not compatible with 64-bit JRE. One option I have is to change over to 32-bit eclipse as well as 32-bit JRE. But I was wondering if same 64-bit Eclipse can be used along with 32-bit JRE also.

Please suggest!

**EDIT:** I guess I was not clear enough in my question. I do understand that I will need to use a 64-bit JRE to run 64-bit Eclipse. I only wanted to make sure that I can have a project in 64-bit Eclipse which uses a 32-bit JRE for execution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just include the 32bit JRE as an additional Java runtime in the configuration and use it for your project.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot use 64-bit Eclipse with 32-bit JRE, but you can have both 32-bit and 64-bit JREs installed on your system. If you find that one or the other Eclipse fails to start in this situation, it is likely finding the wrong JRE. To remedy the situation, add the following lines to the start of your `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-vm
[fullpath]\javaw.exe
```

Comment: He can run a different java "runtime configuration" than the java configuration which is running eclipse.  In other words, yes, he can run 64 bit java in eclipse and 32 bit java in the project's configured "runtime configuration".

Comment: Indeed. If the goal is to develop in 64-bit Eclipse and test in 32-bit Eclipse, you will want both flavors of Eclipse installed as well as both flavors of JRE. Then make sure that the 32-bit variety is configured under target platform in preferences. Define the 32-bit JRE in preferences and then set that JRE in the launch config. If this is still not clear, I can clarify.

Comment: I insalled both 32 bits and 64 bits on my computer. How can I attach the relevant one (32 bits) to eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need create a 32bit jre environment in menu windows/preferences/java/installed jres. Then, you can create a java project and select 32bit jre environment for 32bit java program.